# OneNote now requires Notes.ReadWrite.All,Notes.Read.All permission

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api

I have been backing up and restoring the OneNote pages by using Graph API no problem with 'Directory.Read.All''Sites.ReadWrite.All''User.Read.All' permissions.

But recently customer have reported this error message.

> 40004 Message: The OAuth token provided does not have the necessary
>   scopes to complete the request. Please make sure you are including one
>   or more of the following scopes: Notes.ReadWrite.All,Notes.Read.All

I understand you can change your policy any time but I suggest you provide a certain centralized way to notify the MS-Graph API developers about the changes.

If there is already, and it's not like 'please come and check the API documentation regularly', can you please share here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion. All OneNote Graph APIs need specific notes scopes in the OAuth token. You can refer to this permissions document that has always been there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#notes-permissions

There was a bug why it was working for you before, which we fixed recently.